# What is Pragmatic risk analysis and management?

Tags: test-management, risk-analysis

Going through **ISTQTB** documents found term **PRAM**

> Pragmatic Risk Analysis and Management

Could anyone out there provide a practical example of PRAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](http://54.197.56.127/2011/08/pragmatic-risk-management.html):

> "In pragmatic terms, "risk tolerance" is nothing more than a
>   reflection of a given decision-maker's attitude in a given decision"

In my own head, I have always thought of it - much in the way the article does - as, "D.A.D"

**D** - *Define*

**A** - *Assess*

**D** - *Decide*

> Define:
>
> What do you want to accomplish?  What value are you adding?  What will
>   cost be in both money and workforce?
>
> Assess:
>
> What are my risks?  What are the impacts of *not doing this?*  What
>   are the potential risks if you do?
>
> Decide:
>
> Always have a mitigation strategy for your risks.  Be agile.

I hope you found this helpful!